# Will I get denaturalized if I go to a medical school in Taiwan that is military-affiliated?

Tags: immigration, citizenship, military, dual-citizenship, naturalization

As a naturalized US citizen, I'm interested in understanding the potential repercussions, such as denaturalization or revocation, if I choose to attend a medical school in my home country of Taiwan, which is affiliated with the military. I'm aware that some have suggested that fulfilling mandatory military service in another country wouldn't lead to denaturalization, and Taiwan mandates a 4-month military service for its citizens. However, my concern is if voluntarily enrolling in a military-affiliated medical school, which entails a six-year program including military training to waive the 4-month service requirement, would jeopardize my US citizenship status.
I know that the law says becoming a commissioned or non-commissioned officer of another country is a "Potentially Expatriating Act". It also says the citizenship will be revoked" if they perform certain specified acts voluntarily and with the intention to relinquish U.S. nationality"
But what exactly is the “intention” to relinquish US nationality? Does holding a commissioned or non commissioned officer position automatically count as an intention?

Answer (score 1):

First, a correction about terminology: what you are describing is not "denaturalization", but rather "loss of citizenship". "Denaturalization" refers to the determination that you obtained naturalization fraudulently, or you were otherwise ineligible for naturalization at the time of naturalization, and thus your naturalization is retroactively declared to have been invalid. This does not require that you have performed any potentially expatriating acts, and does not require you to intend to relinquish citizenship, since you are considered to have never validly been a citizen in the first place. On the other hand, the "potentially expatriating acts" deal with loss of US citizenship of someone who properly had US citizenship, and the conditions apply identically to naturalized citizens and citizens from birth. This requires intention to relinquish US citizenship.

Regarding loss of US citizenship, as other answers have mentioned, the Department of State currently has an [administrative presumption](https://fam.state.gov/fam/07fam/07fam1220.html#M1222) that, for several of the potentially expatriating acts (including foreign naturalization, taking foreign oath, serving in a foreign military not in hostilities with the US, or serving in a non-policy position in a foreign government), you are presumed to not intend to relinquish citizenship unless you state otherwise.

But even when this administrative presumption does not apply, e.g. for the potentially expatriating acts not included in the administrative presumption, the potentially expatriating act still does not "automatically count" as intention. The intention must be proved separately from the act, and current law ([8 USC 1481](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1481&num=0&edition=prelim)(b)) requires that a claim of loss of nationality be proven "by a preponderance of the evidence". The US Supreme Court said in [Vance v. Terrazas](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/444/252/) (1980):

> 1. In establishing loss of citizenship, the Government must prove an intent to surrender United States citizenship, not just the voluntary
>    commission of an expatriating act such as swearing allegiance to a
>    foreign nation. Congress does not have any general power to take away
>    an American citizen's citizenship without his "assent," which means an
>    intent to relinquish citizenship, whether the intent is expressed in
>    words or is found as a fair inference from his conduct. The
>    expatriating acts specified in § 349(a) cannot be treated as
>    conclusive evidence of the indispensable voluntary assent of the
>    citizen. The trier of fact must, in the end, conclude that the citizen
>    not only voluntarily committed the expatriating act prescribed in the
>    statute, but also intended to relinquish his citizenship.
> 2. [...] While the statute provides that any of the statutory expatriating acts, if proved, is presumed to have been committed
>    voluntarily, it does not also direct a presumption that the act has
>    been performed with the intent to relinquish United States
>    citizenship, which matter remains the burden of the party claiming
>    expatriation to prove by a preponderance of the evidence. [...]

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While service as a foreign commissioned or noncommissioned officer is potentially expatriating by statute, it only results in loss of nationality if you do it with intent to relinquish US citizenship. Various judicial decisions have made it hard for the US government to establish that intent unless you literally fill out a State Department form saying “I am giving up my citizenship.” In response, the State Department has an administrative presumption that you don’t intend to give up your citizenship through most routine potentially expatriating acts. 7 FAM 1222 says that this presumption applies to cases where a US citizen “[s]erves in the armed services of a foreign state as a commissioned or noncommissioned officer of a foreign state, not engaged in hostilities against the United States.” The presumption also applies if you naturalize in a foreign country, take an oath of allegiance to a foreign country, or take a non-policy-level job with a foreign country. In these four situations, you don’t have to do anything to keep US citizenship — the State Department will assume you wanted to keep it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!